# Can't figure out how to connect objects inside and outside of a class

Tags: python, class, customtkinter

I am working on a dictionary in `customtkinter`. This is the first time I've encountered a need to use classes and I am kinda lost at some point. There is the switch button at the bottom of the definition of the class (`self.switch = customtkinter.CTkSwitch`). The switch should activate-deactivate all buttons (`self.inner_Button = customtkinter.CTkButton`) of every created object of the class at once. But the switch works only with the latest object and it's button. I assume that happens because every time an object of the class is created it overlaps the widget `self.switch.place(relx=0.865, rely=0.26)` because it has always the fixed coordinates. I understand that I somehow need to get the logic related to the switch object out of the class. But I can't connect the switch widget with the class.
To sum up: I need the switch widget to activate-deactivate all button widgets inside all objects of the class at once.

```
import customtkinter
from PIL import Image

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode('light')
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme('dark-blue')

root = customtkinter.CTk()
root.geometry('700x800')
root.title('My dictionary')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)


class WordBox(customtkinter.CTk):

    def __init__(self,
                 word='',
                 translation='',
                 context='',
                 img_path='C:\\testing\\placeholder.jpg'):
    
        super().__init__()
        default_fontsize = 23

        self.label_image = customtkinter.CTkImage(
            Image.open(img_path),
            size=(150, 150))

        if len(word) > 30:
            half_index = int(len(word) / 2)
            space_char_indx = word.find(' ', half_index)
            string_list = list(word)
            string_list[space_char_indx] = '\n'
            word = ''.join(string_list)
            default_fontsize = 17

        if len(context) > 50:
            half_index = int(len(context) / 2)
            space_char_indx = context.find(' ', half_index)
            string_list = list(context)
            string_list[space_char_indx] = '\n'
            context = ''.join(string_list)

        self.outer_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=scroll_frame, width=600, height=150, 
fg_color='#AED5D5')
        self.outer_frame.pack(pady=10, padx=10, side='top')

        self.inner_LabelWord = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self.outer_frame,
                                                      text=word,
                                                      fg_color='#C9D1D8',
                                                      text_color='#0B7BDE',
                                                      font=('Arial Black', default_fontsize),
                                                      width=400, height=50, anchor='nw')
        self.inner_LabelWord.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.inner_LabelTranslation = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self.outer_frame,
                                                             text=translation,
                                                             fg_color='#C9D1D8',
                                                             text_color='black',
                                                             font=('Yu Gothic UI Semibold', 
    default_fontsize), width=400, height=50, anchor='nw')
        self.inner_LabelTranslation.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.inner_LabelContext = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self.outer_frame,
                                                         text=context,
                                                         fg_color='#908D8B',
                                                         text_color='black',
                                                         font=('Dubai', 14),
                                                         width=400, height=50, anchor='nw')
        self.inner_LabelContext.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.inner_PicFrame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=self.outer_frame, 
fg_color='#48E5E0', width=150, height=150)
        self.inner_PicFrame.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=3)
        self.inner_PicLabel = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self.inner_PicFrame, 
image=self.label_image, text='')
        self.inner_PicLabel.pack()

        self.inner_Button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self.outer_frame, width=50, 
height=150, text='O',
                                                    font=('', 20), fg_color='#C9D1D8', 
hover_color='#FFA60B',
                                                    state='disabled')
        self.inner_Button.grid(row=0, column=2, rowspan=3)

        self.switch_var = customtkinter.StringVar(value="off")
        self.switch = customtkinter.CTkSwitch(master=root, text='', command=self.switcher,
                                              variable=self.switch_var, onvalue="on", 
                                              offvalue="off")
        self.switch.place(relx=0.865, rely=0.26)

    def switcher(self):
        print(self.switch_var.get())
        if self.switch_var.get() == 'on':
            self.inner_Button.configure(state='normal')
        if self.switch_var.get() == 'off':
            self.inner_Button.configure(state='disabled')


scroll_frame = customtkinter.CTkScrollableFrame(master=root, width=650, height=500)
scroll_frame.place(relx=0.03, rely=0.3)

cat = WordBox('cat', 'кошка')
dog = WordBox('dog', 'собака')
bird = WordBox('bird', 'птица')
elephant = WordBox('elephant', 'слон')

root.mainloop()
```

And here is an abridged version of the code which represents the gist of my problem. If you want to try it, this block of code below works fine, just copy and paste it (need to pip install customtkinter)

```
import customtkinter

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode('light')
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme('dark-blue')

root = customtkinter.CTk()
root.geometry('700x800')
root.title('MY TEST')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)


class WordBox(customtkinter.CTk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Create the button widget
        self.inner_Button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=root, width=75, height=75, text='O',
                                                    font=('', 20), fg_color='#C9D1D8', hover_color='#FFA60B',
                                                    state='disabled')
        self.inner_Button.pack(padx=10, pady=10, side='top')

        # Create the switcher widget
        self.switch_var = customtkinter.StringVar(value="off")
        self.switch = customtkinter.CTkSwitch(master=root, text='', command=self.switcher,
                                              variable=self.switch_var, onvalue="on", offvalue="off")
        self.switch.place(relx=0.865, rely=0.26)

    # Define the logic which makes the switcher work
    def switcher(self):
        print(self.switch_var.get())
        if self.switch_var.get() == 'on':
            self.inner_Button.configure(state='normal')
        if self.switch_var.get() == 'off':
            self.inner_Button.configure(state='disabled')


button1 = WordBox()
button2 = WordBox()
button3 = WordBox()

root.mainloop()
```

I've tried putting the switcher related code out of the `__init__(self)` block, but still I am unable to connect switcher from the outside with the button inside the `__init__(self)`

Comment: If you want something to apply to all instances, you should use a class attribute rather than an instance attribute.